# talking to .net web service using https

Tags: http, blackberry, https

I have an Android app that talks to .net web service via http over TLS using self-signed server certificate. Now I am trying to figure out how I can accomplish the similar things (Import server certificate into the app and use http get protocol to talk to .net web service) in Blackberry phone.

Reading an article [Blackberry support for HTTPS](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/BlackBerry-Support-for-HTTPS-connection/ta-p/445952), my impression was that it might be more complex than in Android (for example, having Enterprise server and MDS between a phone and web server). Can I use Direct TCP Connection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

HttpsConnection cons=(HttpsConnection) Connector.open("https://xyz.com");

Comment: Pretty much the same as Android java, isn't it? Don't I have to be distracted by MDS, BES? Can I communicate directly to .net web service without them?

Comment: Yes this is same as a Android java. You can use any web service by GET or POST method.